# 3rd party Program focus

Tags: excel, vba

thanks for your amazing support!

Now i have again a question. To get access to some raw datas (i'm working in a call center) we using a website to get an CSV/xls file from our SQL Database (the IT Department doesnt allow me to get direct access to the SQL database).

For an automatic update of my sheet i use an shell command to trigger chrome with the right parameters in the link (chrome starts the download).

Everything works fine but, when i trigger Chrome per shell, i have to minimize chrome again (otherwise you can't see the Excel screen). So i can't find an command to minimize external windows so i'm using shell to minimize all, after that i maximize excel again, works great, but after excel has done the updates, it should activate "VLC Media Player", i tried to use `AppActivate` for that, but its just blikink orange in the taskbar and dont get focus.

Can you help me?

I can share you the code but it's really just the `AppActivate()` line that interest you :)

Thanks again!
Br
Olvier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) from NirSoft is what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sandeep! :) is there mayby another way to do that? I think my it department don't that exe file in our intranet :(

Comment: This is free software and do not need any licence. However, if you have programming experience, it would take about 10~20 lines of code to do that. Even you can find code sample online.